# How to pytest monkeypatch multiple argv arguments?

Tags: pytest, monkeypatching

I'm only able to test **one** argument e.g. *animal*. Every other added argument fails e.g. *name*. What must I change?

`pytest foo.py` returns `pytest: error: the following arguments are required: name`

```
### foo.py ###
import argparse
import pytest
import sys

@pytest.mark.parametrize('animal_input', ['cat'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('name_input', ['tom'])
def test_get_bake_progress(monkeypatch, animal_input, name_input):
    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        m.setattr(sys, 'argv', ['--animal', animal_input])
        m.setattr(sys, 'argv', ['--name', name_input])
        assert foo() == (animal_input)


def foo():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('animal')
    parser.add_argument('name')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    animal = args.animal
    name = args.name
    return animal
```

Comment: You are replacing `sys.argv` with the second `setattr` instead of adding another parameter. You have to `setattr` all attributes at once.

Answer (score 0):

According to @MrBean Bremen and with a small edit from @Ouss:

```
m.setattr(sys, 'argv', [ sys.argv[0], '--animal', animal_input, '--name', name_input])
```

## Fixed code

```py
### foo.py ###
import argparse
import pytest
import sys

@pytest.mark.parametrize('animal_input', ['cat'])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('name_input', ['tom'])
def test_get_bake_progress(monkeypatch, animal_input, name_input):
    with monkeypatch.context() as m:
        m.setattr(sys, 'argv', [ sys.argv[0], '--animal', animal_input, '--name', name_input])
        assert foo() == (animal_input)


def foo():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('animal')
    parser.add_argument('name')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    animal = args.animal
    name = args.name
    return animal
```